# Jersey get credentials from url

Tags: jersey

I have an url like this:

```
http://log:pass@localhost:8080/myendpoint
```

And Jersey endpoint:

```
@GET @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) @Path("/login")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) public Response login(
            @Context HttpHeaders headers, @QueryParam("callback") String callback) 
{
}
```

And ideally I want to get 'log' and 'pass' in my endpoint method. How to do that in Jersey? I tried many endpint method signatures, filters, etc but it shows me

http://localhost instead of http://log:pass@localhost everywhere

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in your front end, you are sending your parameters as a json object using `JSON.stringify()` then back in your endpoint method. Add this as a second argument to that method signature `JsonObject payload`. Then you can access your query parameters within that method as follows

```
String log = payload.getString("log");
String pass = payload.getString("pass");
```

**Revised Version**

```
@Path("/login")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response login(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, @Context HttpHeaders headers, @QueryParam("callback") String callback) {
    URI requestUri = uriInfo.getRequestUri();
    String authority = requestUri.getAuthority(); // authority contains what you need;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use json, just get request in postman. How can I get it from url? This approach related to jsonp basic auth issue. I can't send Authorization header, so I decided to send login/pass in url like I described. How to retrieve it from url?

Comment: Then just add `@QueryParam("log") String log, @QueryParam("pass") String pass` to your endpoint method signature

Comment: Thanks, but you don't understand. I add login and pass before domain, and they don't have their names. 'log' and 'pass' it's just login and password. Any strings may be on their places. 'mylogin', 'mypassword'. It's not names, but random strings

Comment: So `@QueryParam()` takes the name of your query parameter, it automatically extracts the value for you and "inject" it into the method argument. You must know the names of the query params beforehand right?

Comment: Thanks  So let's take this url http://test:12345@localhost:8080/myapp/jersey/auth/login  There're NO named parameters. test - this is login 12345-password. They maximum have their positions, but not names

Comment: You can inject a `UriInfo` just like you do the headers, then extract the `URI` object from it, then you can access that part. So `@Context UriInfo uriInfo`

Comment: Check out the docs for `UriInfo` [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html)

Comment: Thanks guys, but the issue is the format I asked you about is no longer supported by IE, Chrome and other browsers. The problem was that chrome just remove these parameters from URL, and IE complains that request is malformed. So this question is not still relevant. Thank you guys

Comment: Yeah send login info over `GET` is not recommended anyways. But if you are interested, I've posted a revised version based on what you described

Comment: No worries at all